# Struct Array Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I keep running into a problem with reading values of a struct array, where I keep getting a segmentation fault. Here is the code:

```
int main() 
{
    /* Get PATH Environment Variable */
    char *pathv[MAX_PATHS];
    char cmd_line[MAX_ARGS];
    struct command_t cmd[3];         //THIS IS THE STRUCT ARRAY
    size_t len = 0;

    /* Parse The Path */
    ParsePath(pathv);

    while(1) {

        /* Print Continuous Prompt */
        PrintPrompt();

        /* Read Command Line & Parse It */
        ReadCommand(cmd_line);

        ParseCommand(cmd_line, cmd);    //PASSING IT TO THIS METHOD
    }

    return 0;
}



int ParseCommand(char *buffer, struct command_t *cmd)
{
    char *name = "Test";
    cmd[0].name;  //IF THIS IS COMMENTED OUT AND THE OTHER LINE AS WELL, PROGRAM RUNS
    printf("%s\n", cmd[0].name); //FINE....THESE TWO LINES CAUSE SEG. FAULT
}
```

```
struct command_t {
    char *name;
    int argc;
    char *argv[MAX_ARGS];
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: where do you assign to `cmd[0].name`?

Comment: You might also like to show us the definition of `struct command_t`.

Comment: Sorry, I just added my struct code. This struct is in a separate header file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize `cmd` nor write any data.   Accessed uninitialized data is undefined behavior in C so yes it is valid to crash.  You need to write something into `cmd[0].name` before reading from it.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I found out what the problem was...I forgot to put = name...WOW. Sorry guys! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In C, when you declare a variable without assigning a value to it doesn't mean it is empty. It may point to memory garbage from stuff that was ran previously.

Your attempt to `printf()` whats in `cmd[0].name` without initializing it can be catastrophic.

You should initialize each variable in your struct before trying to access its value, or at least zero-fill everything in order to make it safe to read:

```
memset(cmd, 0, sizeof(*cmd) * 3);
```

Comment: Isn't zero-filling `memset(cmd, sizeof(*cmd), 0)`?

Comment: @mLstudent33 Not quite, but yes, forgot a parameter there.